# Hadoop Community

Tags: discussion

I searched Stack Exchange communities, but I didn't find a **community for Hadoop Enthusiasts.**

So can we have the same?

What is the process for this?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Close votes are okay, but the downs are imho without a reason.

Answer (score 7):

The community for Hadoop enthusiasts [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop).

Comment: Link provided is the hadoop tagged questions.Not community.

Comment: @TKHN Tag followers on language or technology tags form the expert communities in stack overflow.